# Swingx DefaultColumnControlPopup with still open menu

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I have `MyTable` which is extension of the `JXTable`:

```
public class MyTable extends JXTable{...}
```

Works fine as expected. Now I want to let DefaultColumnControlPopup menu still open after click onto element in popup menu so user can do multiple clicks without annoying clicks on ColumnControlButton.

Does someone know how to do it?

I had been trying to solve based on [this tutorial](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/) but without success.

Comment: you need a custom ColumnControl, have a look at the visual test (in the test hierarchy, probably table packeag), there's an example using a popup with a list).  Unrelated: why do you extend the xtable? Typically, you shouldn't, everything (that we thought of, at least :-) is fully configurable without subclassing.

Comment: @kleopatra class extended because i need to remove horizontal scroll, pack all and pack selected (default added in every `ColumnControlButton`) and control every `JCheckBoxMenuItem` through `setEnabled()` and `setSelected()` -two from eleven columns have to be shown permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some elaboration, it's easy if one know how to do it - as obvious...

Whole solution for others:

I have class in which I'm using JXTable:

```
JXTable myTable = new JXTable(new MyTableModel())
...use_table_as_usually...
```

class for the table:

```
public class MyTable extends JXTable{
    public MyTable(AbstractTableModel model){
        super(model);
        //remove items for horizontal scrollbar, pack and packall
        this.getActionMap().remove("column.horizontalScroll");
        this.getActionMap().remove("column.packAll");
        this.getActionMap().remove("column.packSelected");
        //first two columns should be shown permanently
        ColumnControlButton controlButton = new ColumnControlButton(this){
            @Override
            protected ColumnControlPopup createColumnControlPopup(){
                return (new NFColumnControlPopup());
            }

            class NFColumnControlPopup extends DefaultColumnControlPopup{
                @Override
                public void addVisibilityActionItems(List<? extends AbstractActionExt> actions){
                    for(int i = 0; i < actions.size(); i++){
                        AbstractActionExt action = actions.get(i);
                        JCheckBoxMenuItem chk = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(action);
                        chk.setUI(new KeepOpenCheckBox());
                        //disable first two items but they will be still shown greyed
                        if(i == 0 || i == 1){
                            chk.setEnabled(false);
                            chk.setSelected(false);
                        }
                        else{
                            chk.setEnabled(true);
                            chk.setSelected(true);
                        }
                        chk.addItemListener(action);
                        super.addItem(chk);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        this.setColumnControl(controlButton);
    }
}
```

and finaly custom class to keep `ColumnControlPopup` open:

```
public class KeepOpenCheckBox extends BasicCheckBoxMenuItemUI{
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c){
        return new KeepOpenCheckBox();
    }

    protected void doClick(MenuSelectionManager msm){
        menuItem.doClick(0);
    }
}
```

That's all. In this example are mixed 3 things:
-how to remove unwanted items for horizontal scrollbar, pack and packall;
-how to disable some column controls from `ColumnControlPopup` but keep them showed with grey and without check mark;
-how to keep `ColumnControlPopup` open after click on `JCheckBoxMenuItem`;

Solution is based on some resources I have found around on the Internet but some informations was old or not working (works in `JMenu` but no in popup menu).

Comment: glad you found a solution, just there are a couple of better-nots :-) - a tableColumnExt has a property hideable which is respected by the default columnControl (though buggy in initial setup, see the issue tracker for a work-around) -don't extend JXTable, instead _configure_ it with your custom control -for not including the other actions, implement the popup's addAdditionalActions to do nothing (as you have to extend the control for other reasons) -setting the ui on individual instances is brittle (won't survive a toggle of LAF) and breaks the visuals (for LAF's != basic/metal)

Comment: @kleopatra i agree with you but working example should be nice. have been looking around but not found any (wchich could mean that i have been looking wrong).